# Build a project in release mode without changing build mode?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, build

I have a solution with a lot of project, Default build configuration manager is Debug.

Some times i need build only one project in **release** mode, So it force me to change solution build mode to release that consume **long time** to change it and after build to switch back to debug mode.

Question is any way to achieve this purpose quickly without doing this above stages?

Thanks.

Comment: It consumes **long time** on my big solution too sometimes. But it goes back to **faster** after a restart and some general **cleanup** of the system (delete temp files, make sure disk drives, at least the system one has 20% or more free space, etc..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into the batch build menu. You can select a particular project and have only that one build.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command line.

Use [`msbuild`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) passing in the project file and set the configuration property to release.

In a Visual Studio Command Prompt window:

```
msbuild /property:Configuration=Release <path to project>
```